# property of the product of subgroups of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group and $H,K\leq G$ are subgroups then we can prove thefollowing fact easily: If $H\subset N_G(K)$ or $K\subset N_G(H)$ then $HK\leq G$.

But I am interested is the converse of this is true or not?

I was trying to prove that the converse holds but was not able to do it. So I guess there is some kind of counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is not true. Look for example at $G=S_4$. Let $H$ be a $2$-Sylow subgroup and $K$ a $3$-Sylow subgroup. Then $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=24$ and hence $HK=G$. So $HK$ is obviously a subgroup. But now we can see none of the two subgroups is contained in the normalizer of the other. I assume here that you know the Sylow subgroups of $S_4$ are not normal in it. So let's assume $H\leq N_G(K)$. Lagrange's theorem tells us that $8$ divides $|N_G(K)|$. But we also know that $K\leq N_G(K)$ and hence $3$ divides $|N_G(K)|$ as well. Well, from here we conclude that $24$ divides $|N_G(K)|$. But that means $G=N_G(K)$ and hence $K\trianglelefteq G$ which is a contradiction. In the same way you can show $K$ is not contained in $N_G(H)$.

Comment: Generally, I am familiar with Sylow theorems but could you explain why Sylow subgroups of $S_4$ are not normal? Maybe this is trivial.

Comment: I guess it's related with the number of Sylow subgroups. If Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal then $N_p=1$ where by $N_p$ I denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups. But I guess that in our case $N_2$ and $N_3$ are not equal to $1$. But I did not check it since have not paper and pen right now :)

Comment: You can check $\langle (123)\rangle$,$\langle (234)\rangle$ are both $3$-Sylow subgroups and $\langle (1234),(13)\rangle$,$\langle (1324),(12)\rangle$ are both $2$-Sylow subgroups. (the $2$-Sylow subgroups are isomorphic to the diherdral group $D_4$).

Comment: What about my suggestion?

Comment: Well, if you show there is more than one Sylow subgroup of each type then you get $N_p>1$ for every prime $p$. Wasn't that what you suggested?

Comment: Sorry i was reviewing your answer and ran into the following question: You proved that $H$ is not subgroup of $N_G(K)$, right? but does it follow that $H$ not subset of $N_G(K)$?

Comment: Yes, of course it does follow. Both $H$ and $N_G(K)$ are groups with respect to the same binary operation (the operation of $G$). So if $H$ was a subset of $N_G(K)$ then it was a subset which is also a group with respect to the operation of $N_G(K)$ and hence by definition a subgroup of $N_G(K)$.

Comment: The best! You have clarified all my question! I accept your answer. Thanks :)